# Why babies these days are rushed to eat adults' food at family table?

Tags: toddler, babyfood, baby-led-weaning

The guidelines I received these days is to let babies as young as 12 months to eat whatever the family is eating without breaking them down in the mixer first. At 12 months we ('80s kids) still ate porridge and soft food. Why is that? The babies don't even have enough teeth to munch the food properly, so most of the times they just swallow the food whole. I don't find babies these days become healthier either eating like this. If anything, it burdens their digestive system too much and too early.

I suspect this is just because day-cares don't want to invest too much time to feed their charge properly. It's easier to do the so-called BLW (just scatter the food on a tray and the babies will clean them) than to spoon feed. Were these "new" guidelines conceived with the best interest of the babies in mind?

I don't like bringing this up with my pediatrician or with other mothers around me, because anyone questioning THE guidelines is quickly dubbed as someone wearing a tin-foil hat. I did ask once, but didn't get any real answer except to just follow it. I still break down my baby's food in the mixer first. He's 14 months old, taller than his "peers" (84 cm) and has a healthy weight too.

I'm ready to change my mind if there's a logical reasoning behind this. Thank you.

Comment: For most of human history people didn't have the means to easily blend or process their food. One could argue that baby led weaning - just giving your kids cooked, soft foods is the more natural way to teach them to eat.

Focusing on purees likely has more to do with paranoia over choking, than any type of meaningful science.

Comment: @mcraenich That's true, but I think, before mixer was invented, babies were breasted longer too. In my grandma's generation, their babies were breastfed until 3-4 y/o. Afaik it's only recently that a one-year-old baby is expected to eat the same things as other (adult) family members (cmiiw).

Comment: Back then breast-milk was an excellent source of nutrition in lieu of quality nutrition in the environment, so if it was cheap and available it would make sense to do it longer (and some people still do it for a longer period of time). But kids develop teeth at a young age for a reason, because they need to learn to eat solid food and eventually 'wean' off of milk. Pediatricians wouldn't recommend giving up breast milk or formula before age 1, but after that it's not a big issue nutritionally, if their diet is otherwise fine.

Comment: Do you happen to have a source for these guidelines that do not seem reasonable?  It has been awhile since I prepared food for a 1 year old, but I recall most of their meals still being fairly mushy, or at least fairly small in size and easy to break apart with their tongue. Not just 'what the family is having no modifications' as you're implying.

Comment: @Zibbobz in the first comment I mentioned 'giving your kids cooked, soft foods'. I'm recommending standard baby-led weaning.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, my comment is directed at @ShaNon the question asker, not your recommendations for feeding.

Comment: @Zibbobz I have them in German. It doesn't say giving babies steak or the likes, but in my parents' time it was just still unthinkable to give babies soft food that they had to swallow whole (like, soft broccoli). Usually everything was blended until the baby had enough teeth to chew properly.

Comment: @ShaNon babies' gums are fairly hard; they are capable of "gumming" soft foods (instead of chewing them). They don't actually swallow food whole, they kind of mash them with their gums (and possibly tongue). So this only works on foods soft enough to get mashed like that.

Comment: As an aside, different things work for different babies. My baby (8 months) won't eat from a spoon I am holding, and isn't quite capable of eating with a spoon herself. She insists on feeding herself, so I put small pieces of sweet potato or banana on her tray, and she can pick them up and eat them. Some babies do much better with purees and gag on anything with texture. It really depends on the baby.

Answer (score 3):

First it seems surprising to me that you observe the historical trend in that direction. To me it seems that today kids are still fed specially prepared baby food well into toddler age whereas when I was a baby first experiences with real food were made at a few months old and at around 1 year of age kids were giving slightly adapted grown-up food. That might me country dependent.

For your actual question I would suggest to look at grey zones. It is not either blend everything or offer unaltered grown-up food, there are many in-between steps.

For example walnuts or a piece of steak are indeed tricky for a 1-year old to eat. But a boiled potato or a piece of cooked fish are perfectly fine without teeth if cut into bitsized chunks. So look at your grown-up plate and decide which parts of it are suitable to try for a kid and which ones are not. Experiment. Adapt from experience and with age.

Finally blending everything means food looses almost all texture. So they miss out on the experience and also never have a chance to learn that food should be chewed. They just learn that food should be swallowed whole and that chew toys should be used for there natural chewing urges.

*Edit:* As pointed out by RDavies in the comment, giving them finger food instead of feeding a mush additionally allows them handling the food themselves. They learn to grab the food and coordinate to put it in their mouth, experience the different textures also with their hands and of course will greatly enjoy doing that compared to just being spoon fed.

Comment: being presented with appropriately prepared finger foods also allows the child to practice their pincer grip when they pick up and manipulate food with their hands, as well as feel all sorts of different textures both with their hands and their mouth.

Comment: @RDavies Excellent point, I will add that to my answer.